# How to use the Application Search API and get the Android Application version number from Playstore using mashape api

Tags: android, mashape

I have to get the application version number and details of an android application from the google play store.

I have checked the mashape api.
Please refer the URL.
https://www.mashape.com/maxcanna/google-play-store

Can you confirm if the apis can be used to fetch details in free? Because when Im trying to test the endpoit it takes the page to subsription page for payment.

For example, if I want to get the latest version of Watsapp application from the playstore in my java application, can I use the api - 
https://gplaystore.p.mashape.com/applicationDetails

What should I provide input for the "id" and "X-Mashape" key for the getting the Watsapp version number from the playstore using this api to perform the Test Endpoint. Can you help quicky with the steps needed to use this api.

Thanks a lot.

Thanks and regards,
Pallavi Roy.

Answer (score 0):

This API is Freemium: That means you need to pay for some of the feature.
If you look at the "*Pricing*" tab on the page you have linked you can see what the pricing looks like.

If you signup to Mashape and subscribe to the API (you need a valid credit card) you will see the `X-Mashape` key will be auto-populated for you.
`id` is the id of the application you want to track.
If you look at the page for "Whatsapp" on the Google play store:

`https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.whatsapp&hl=en`

You will see that in the URL the id is `com.whatsapp`. That's what you need to use in the `id` field